# Python script in Docker can't find module in subdirectory

Tags: python, docker, python-module

My project structure is as follows:

```
.
├── my_script.Dockerfile
├── README.rst
├── log
│   └── my_script.log
├── pickles
├── requirements.txt
├── requirements_my_script.txt
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── module.py
│   ├── other_scripts
│   │   └── my_script.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       └── logging_utils.py
```

my_script.Dockerfile is as follows:

```sh
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements_my_script.txt requirements_my_script.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements_my_script.txt
COPY src/. .
CMD ["python3", "other_scripts/my_script.py"]
```

my_script.py:

```py
import logging

from src.utils.logging_utils import start_logger


def main(logger):
    # some code here
    logger.info('done')
    sleep(120)
       
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    logger = start_logger('my_script.log')
    try:
        logger.info('Starting..')
        main(logger)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.critical('Crashed with error: {}'.format(e))
```

And the logging_utils.py:

```py
import os
import logging

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

def start_logger(filename, level='INFO'): # INFO or DEBUG
    # # LOGGING
    log_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'project_folder_name', 'log')
    if not os.path.exists(log_folder):
            os.makedirs(log_folder)
    log_filename = filename

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logFormatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    if level == 'DEBUG':
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    else:
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # add a rotating handler
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(log_folder, log_filename), maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=1)
    handler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

This runs flawlessly on my machine, but when I build the docker and try to run it I get the following error:

```sh
from src.utils.logging_utils import start_logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I tried several different COPY statements in the dockerfile but without success.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I tried this dockerfile as well:

```sh
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements_my_script.txt requirements_my_script.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements_my_script.txt
COPY src/ src/
CMD ["python3", "src/other_scripts/my_script.py"]
```

But I get the exact same error.

Comment: Did you try `from utils.logging_utils import start_logger` in your `my_script.py` file?

Comment: Fails already in my local machine:
from utils.logging_utils import start_logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Comment: I think It is because of your `WORKDIR` inside DockerFile. You should change that or Copy the `src` dir too, because you are copying only src contents. not that dir

Comment: Changed the dockerfile to:
```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements_my_script.txt requirements_my_script.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements_my_script.txt
COPY src/ src/
CMD ["python3", "src/other_scripts/my_script.py"]
```
but I get the same error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to solve this without refactoring the code is adding ENV as follows in the dockerfile:

```sh
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements_my_script.txt requirements_my_script.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements_my_script.txt
COPY src/ src/
ENV PYTHONPATH /app
CMD ["python3", "src/other_scripts/my_script.py"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from `my_script.py`:

```
from src.utils.logging_utils import start_logger
```

Add these lines to your `my_script.py`:

```
from sys import path as syspath
from os import path as ospath
syspath.append(ospath.join(ospath.dirname(ospath.realpath(__file__)),'..','utils')) # To find out where to look, import the utils path into the script path
from logging_utils import start_logger
```

And do this in `Dockerfile` :

```
COPY src/ src/
```

Comment: This works as a workaround, thanks. Will mark as solved in the next days if there's no better answer.
BTW the fact that Docker doesn't find modules in a parallel folder is a bug IMO

Answer (score 0):

When your code does its `import`

```py
from src.utils.logging_utils ...
```

Python looks for a `./src/utils/logging_utils.py`, relative to the current directory and anything else in the Python search path.  But in your Dockerfile, you strip out the `src` directory:

```bash
COPY src/. .
```

copies the *contents of* the `src` directory into the current directory.  I'm guessing if you `docker run --rm your-image ls`, you'll see the `utils` directory immediately in the application directory and not in the `src` subdirectory.

If you need to copy a subdirectory from your host into a subdirectory in your image, you need to repeat the directory name on both sides of `COPY`, like

```bash
COPY src/ src/
```

Comment: Please see my other comment, I tried COPY src/ src/ and it didn't work (same error)